# Visibility of set outside of infinite loop filling it

Tags: rust

I'm defining a `HashSet` just outside of a `loop` that will eventually fill it.

Something like:

```
let mut keys = HashSet::new();
loop {
    let mss = try!(con.poll()); // taken from kafka-rust
    // some code
    keys.insert(stuff);
    // some code
    try!(con.commit_consumed());
}
```

Now I have the obvious `reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement`:

```
note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 1 at 28:34...
  --> src/main.rs:28:35
   |
28 |     let mut keys = HashSet::new();
   |                                   ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 30:35
  --> src/main.rs:30:36
   |
30 |         let mss = try!(con.poll());
   |                                    ^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, so I cannot help. Please produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally on an online Rust compiler such as [the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/).

Comment: Also, post the *full* error message that `rustc` emits (and preferably use 1.12 to get the clearer error messages that should explain the issue to you).

Comment: It's basically not very different from https://github.com/spicavigo/kafka-rust/blob/master/examples/example-consume.rs where there HashSet would be declared around line 32 and used around line 42

Comment: Goodness, attempting to find a good duplicate in the mass of borrow-checker issues on stackoverflow is like looking for a needle in a pile of hay :(

Comment: Yep. a simple `.to_string()` fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthieu M. If it's hard to see an obvious duplicate, maybe it's better to leave the question open and provide an answer. It may be even harder for future readers to see the similarity.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: The problem is finding the duplicate (because there are so many different situations the borrow-checker complains about). I believe that the two questions linked here are duplicates enough that they ought to be marked as such. Case in point, the OP found the solution to his issue following the duplicate mark :)